# Problem bind DoubleProperty to my modified TextField

Tags: javafx, properties, textfield, bind

I'm trying to bind a DoubleProperty to a TextField and the only binding functionnal is the bidirectionnal and not the unidirectionnal binding.

My specific TextField :

```
public class DoubleTextField extends TextField{

    public DoubleTextField() {
        super();
        Pattern validDoubleText = Pattern.compile("-?(\\d*)|(\\d+\\.\\d*)");

        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> doubleCheck = change -> {
            String newText = change.getControlNewText();
            if (validDoubleText.matcher(newText).matches()) {
                return change;
            } else
                return null;
        };
    
        this.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Double>(new DoubleStringConverter(), null, doubleCheck));
     }
}
```

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    GridPane gpTest;

    @FXML
    TextField tfUSDT;

    Model model;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        this.model = new Model();
    
        DoubleTextField dtfPrice = new DoubleTextField();
    
        gpTest.add(dtfPrice, 1, 0);
    
    tfUSDT.textProperty().bind(model.getDpActualUsdt().asString("%f"));
    //dtfPrice.textProperty().bind(model.getDpActualPrice().asString("%f"));
    dtfPrice.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.getDpActualPrice(), new NumberStringConverter());
    }

    public void modifyUSDT(ActionEvent e) {
        this.model.getDpActualUsdt().set(50);
    }
 
    public void modifyPrice(ActionEvent e) {
        this.model.getDpActualPrice().set(50);
    }
}
```

```
public class Model {

    private DoubleProperty dpActualUsdt, dpActualPrice;
    
    
    public Model() {
        
        dpActualPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        dpActualUsdt  = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    }
    
    public void setDpActualUsdt(DoubleProperty dpActualUsdt) {
        this.dpActualUsdt = dpActualUsdt;
    }

    public void setDpActualPrice(DoubleProperty dpActualPrice) {
        this.dpActualPrice = dpActualPrice;
    }

    public DoubleProperty getDpActualPrice() {
        return dpActualPrice;
    }

    public DoubleProperty getDpActualUsdt() {
        return dpActualUsdt;
    }
```

}

```
<FlowPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="gpTest">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="tfUSDT" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#modifyUSDT" text="Modify USDT" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#modifyPrice" text="Modify Price" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
```

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        
        FXMLLoader fxml = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/ihm.fxml"));
        Pane mainPane   = fxml.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Here are my classes

With this the code work as expected but if i comment `dtfPrice.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.getDpActualPrice(), new NumberStringConverter())` and decomment `//dtfPrice.textProperty().bind(model.getDpActualPrice().asString("%f"));`

He doesn't work

Thanks for everyone helping me !

Comment: There is no need for a subclass here. Just use a plain `TextField` and set the text formatter in the `initialize()` method. Then (since you have a reference to the text formatter) you can just bind the double property directly to the text formatter's `valueProperty`. (I can't diagnose why it's not working without a [mre].)

Comment: Also note that your `DoubleTextField`s are not actually displayed anywhere, unless there is more code in the `initialize()` method that you simply omitted. So you won't see any changes simply for that reason.

Comment: My DoubleTextField is add on a GridPane just below in the initialize() method.

And yes, if i replace my DoubleTextField by a simple TextField it work but i would like to learn different things than the one i already know.

After a few tries, the problem come from the TextFormatter, if i don't bind the TextFormatter on the constructor of my DoubleTextField, the uniDirectionnal bind work, do you know why ?

Comment: Create a [mre] and edit the question to include it. It’s impossible to tell what’s genuinely missing as an error, and might be causing the problem you describe, and what you’ve just chosen to omit for brevity (which just confuses other readers).

Comment: Done, i've added the FXML and main class too.

Comment: Well that's just weird. Unless I'm missing something, that's a bug. There seems to be some strange interaction between the text formatter's filter and the binding. It looks like the formatter is causing a change in its value (and the text field's text) when the filter is invoked, which reverts the value to its current value, updating the model. Or something like that. You can use listeners as a workaround.

Comment: I've find from where an error come from. I'm using "." in my TextFormatter as a french while the bindingProperty only understand the "," for the double value. That doesn't solve everything but i can move forward !